# Is closing resources in try block accepted?

Tags: java, exception, io

A beginners book on Java has the following code in it. This book also explains about exceptions very well, and since I understood how exception works, I got a question about the following code.

For some reason if FileWriter class throws an exception, `writer.close()` wouldn't be executed. Therefore I think the best place to close the writer object is in a finally block. Even prior to this I have seen many code written like this, where the resource will be closed in the try block itself. I think there is no point in doing so. Only when there is no exception the resource will be closed.

Am I wrong? What is the best way to close resources in java. Should we never write code like the following?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

       try{
         FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");
         writer.write("i am writing");
         writer.close();
       }catch(IOException e){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }

    }
```

Comment: You are correct, its best to close the writer object in the finally block, however, since this writer object is part of the try catch, it cannot be accessed in the finally. For that, you need to declare the variable outside the try block.

Comment: You are correct, the proper place is final. Of course, that can throw another exception within final; and so some people dont like that. Btw: nowadays, one should use try-with-resources

Comment: Since Java 7 you can also use try-with-resources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @cyber-rookie, it is probably best to close resources in a finally block.

Java 7 introduced "try-with-resources" in order to cut down on programming mistakes...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

You can now write...

```
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt")) {
        writer.write("i am writing");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The compiler will add the extra code to close the writer at the end of the block for you

Comment: What if I had multiple resources to be closed?

Comment: @DesirePRG - You can separate then with semi-colons, for example... try ( Resource res1 = new ClosableResource(...); Resource res2 = new ClosableResource(...) ) { ... }

Answer (score 3):

If your are using Java 7, the best approach is to use try with resource. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

```
 try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt")) {
   writer.write("i am writing");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are right, resource should be closed in `finally` block.

as of `java 7` you can use try-with-resource also as :

```
try (BufferedReader br =
               new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
```

Because the `BufferedReader` instance is declared in a `try-with-resource` statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the `try` statement completes `normally or abruptly` if these resources implements `AutoCloseable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience we would utilise the `finally` clause of a try-catch:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");
        writer.write("i am writing");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

PS: Place this in separate method and throw the exception, let the class using this handle exceptions.

Comment: Seems I am behind, java7 has a much cleaner way to handle this now-a-days.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to a comment to add multiple resources in a try with resource block:

```
try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt"); BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))){
        // you can put many AUTOCLOSEABLE objects in try with resource. Just seperate them with ";"  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

At work (Java 6), we close the resources in the TRY block then also do a defensive close in the FINALLY block.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader;
try {
  //initialize and do something with the bufferedReader
   bufferedReader.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    // notify the user 
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // notify the user 
} finally {
    if (bufferedReader != null) {
        try {
           //defensive close
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // this will be thrown if bufferedReader is already closed (in Try block, so can be leave to blank

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not do the close() only in the inner try block?

Comment: @Bret - Because while using the bufferedReader in the try block, you may get exceptions, making the bufferedReader.close() in try block not being executed, this is where the closing in finally block comes to the rescue

Comment: If you removed it from the "try" block, it would get executed in the "finally" block anyway. If that throws an exception it will get handled in the second catch block, right? If you keep both in, then if the first one works (due to normal operation), it will be called again in the finally block and that will always throw an exception (and handle it) because it has already been closed once (presuming the implementation of close always throws an exception if it is already closed...)